# redirect to same component under different conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect to same component but under diffract conditions and i am using windows.location.pathname as a way to know when the user is hitting the second endpoint my question is there a way to know the current location ? I tried to use context but it wont work because I don't want the context provider to give state to the main page that I am redirecting from also could my approach be considered bad ?

```js
  <Route path='/creator' exact component={maincomponent} />
  <Route path='/viewer' exact component={maincomponent} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn the **current path**, you can use `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`.

For example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function PathView() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentPath = location.pathname

  return <span>{currentPath}</span>
}
```

But if you want to use **Routes** with if condition, you can simply use `{}`.

For example:

```
{"YOUR_VARIABLE" === "YOUR_VARIABLE" ? (
  <Route path='/creator' exact component={maincomponent} />
) : (
  <Route path='/viewer' exact component={maincomponent} />
)
```